# Check if a string contains several chars using substr in PHP

Tags: php

I need to check if a string has several keys. Is there a way to make it simpler than the code below :

```
$flag = substr($serial, 0, 1) == 'D' || substr($serial, 0, 1) == '1' || substr($serial, 0, 1) == 'B' || substr($serial, 0, 1) == 'E' ||substr($serial, 0, 1) == 'X' || substr($serial, 0, 1) == 'Z';
```

I need something like the (invalid) example below. Note that i need to check if ANY of this keys (D, 1, B etc) exists in the first position of my $serial string.

```
$flag = substr($serial, 0, 1) in ('D','1','B','E','X','7');
```

Thanks !

Comment: Use [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) in place of `in`, or better yet [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) to probe the string directly.

Comment: `substr($serial, 0, 1)` doesn't imply "ANY position of my string" - but only the first character

Comment: Sorry, i meant any of my keys (D,1,B) exists in the first position of my string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can access the substring using `[]` notation.
2. [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array)

Sample:

```
$flag = in_array($serial[0], ['D','1','B','E','X','7']);
```

Alternative, since this allows very complex expressions, which I think you might need anyway:

```
preg_match($serial, '/^[D1BEX7]/')
```

See http://regular-expressions.info.

Comment: "if this keys (D, 1, B etc) exists in ANY position of my string"

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally also use a regex for this, as that's relatively concise:

```
preg_match("/^[D1BEX7]/", $serial)
```

But if you want to go for low-level string functions, [`strcspn`](http://php.net/strcspn) makes a suitable alternative:

```
!strcspn($serial, "D1BEX7")
```

It returns a positive number unless your input string starts with one of the given symbols. Which is why a simple `!` negation suffices as check. **Caveat**: the input string shouldn't be empty here.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you intend to do:

```
<?php
    $arrFlags   = array('D','1','B','E','X','7');
    $needle     = substr($serial, 0,1);
    $flag       = null;

    if(in_array( $needle , $arrFlags) ){
        //DO SOMETHING WITH THE $serial VARIABLE: IT CONTAINS ANY ONE OF ['D','1','B','E','X','7']
        //PERHAPS, ASSIGN $needle TO THE VARIABLE $flag (REDUNDANT THOUGH)      
        $flag = $needle;
    }
    // IN A COMPACT WAY; YOU CAN REMOVE THE IF STATEMENT ABOVE (INCLUDING THE $flag VARIABLE) & WRITE:
    $flag = ( in_array($needle, $arrFlags) ) ? $needle : null;
```

Hope this snippet helps...